# Need to move ID to Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a submission document through Google Forms & Google Spreadsheets.  I have created a form that emails data for approval.  The email includes a URL link which is contains a unique ID.  This link is connected to a second form for approval/denial of the submission.  I am having difficulty getting this unique ID linked to the approval/denial process form.  I believe I need to reference this ID so that it will approve the correct entry in my spreadsheet.  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to reference my ID through my second form or give me another idea on how to do this?

```js
var d = new Date(); 
var ID = d.getTime(); 
approvalLink = "docs.google.com/forms"; 
approvalLink = approvalLink + "?id=" + ID
```

Comment: Can you show us some code you already have?

Comment: So I have created a Google form for a submission.  It emails out a URL with the ID as the time in macroseconds.   var d = new Date();
  var ID = d.getTime();  approvalLink = "https://docs.google.com/forms";
  approvalLink = approvalLink + "?id=" + ID.  I have the ID emailing - example- https://docs.google.com/forms/?id=1519414402659.  This goes to an approval/denial form question.  I need help trying to get that ID (in this example 1519414402659) to be shown as part of my form questions or show in the spreadsheet I have linked to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this on the live forms. Form Script code doesn't run until after the form is submitted.

**However** you could generate a pre-filled form url for the 2nd approval/denial form that fills in a question with your ID (PS. Think about [using a UUID](https://gist.github.com/superstrong/71ec75b9d143b88490f6) instead of timestamp).

```
var form = FormApp.openById("2nd Form ID");
var response = form.createResponse();
var items = form.getItems();
var item = items[0].asTextItem();
var itemResponse = text.createResponse('my text');
response.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
var url = response.toPrefilledUrl();
```

You use this `url` to present a form with that questions that already has your ID filled in. Then when your 2nd form is submitted you can reference that question.

The url this generates will end in something like: `?entry.2623445234=SomeText`.